# dynamic tooltip for multiline in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm building a complicated multiline graph with zoom, brushing, checkboxes etc. I was able to get this all work but stuck in getting the tooltip working.
I would like to get something like this

http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2657838

A line with all the path value at a particular x cordinate

```
var vertical = d3.select("#main-graph")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "remove")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "19")
.style("width", "1px")
.style("height", "380px")
.style("top", "10px")
.style("bottom", "30px")
.style("left", "0px")
.style("background", "#fff");

d3.select("#main-graph")
.on("mousemove", function(){
mousex = d3.mouse(this);
mousex = mousex[0] + 220 ;
vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
.on("mouseover", function(){  
mousex = d3.mouse(this);
mousex = mousex[0] +220 ;
vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
});
```

Currently i've this above code to get the line. How would i go about getting the data of all the lines on hover now. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [scale.invert](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-invert) function to get the actual value from the mousex value.

```
var xValue = xScale.invert(mousex);
```

Once you have the xValue, use [array bisector](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_bisector) to find the index of the value in the array.

To declare the bisector function:

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
```

and here's how to use it:

```
var index = bisectDate(data, xValue, 1);
```

Once you have the index, then you can choose the nearest between index, index - 1 and index + 1 values and get the all the yValues and xValues from the data.

```
var finalIndex = getDesiredIndex(data, index); //Implement getDesiredIndex to get the left, right or center whatever index you think is perfect for your graph.
```

my assumption is that your data is in the from of array of objects. So `data[finalIndex].yValue1, data[finalIndex].yValue2` ..... should be what you are looking for.

If you need me to provide you with more concrete implementation or working example then add a jsFiddle and I can edit it for you.

Comment: Thanks yogesh for your response. So here is the fiddle with a basic version.
http://jsfiddle.net/aEMSh/6/
I will try implementing yours. If you can give me insight seeing this example than it would be helpful.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aEMSh/7/. I have printed everything to console on mousemove. I will leave it upto you to determine the way you want to display it to the end user. It should not be difficult to display a line at the current mouse position and then you should also be able to easily get a div at the current mouse position.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, Is it possible to have circles on all the line nodes on hover of mouse over the graph. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: It surely is possible. Once you know the nearest xvalue and yvalues. So by now you know the xvalues and yvalues. From xvalues and yvalues you can compute back the x and y points from the scales. Once you have x and y values draw circles at that points. For easy of it you can put them in a seperate g block. And before drawing new circles always remove or delete the old circles.

Comment: Let me know if you get it working. If you still have troubles getting it to work put whatever you have tried in a fiddle and i can clean it up for you.

Comment: Hi Yogesh. Need a help. Can i have x axis tick values at first point indexed to first date irrespective of d3 auto scale.
Some thing like my x axis should look like this

23Jan2013 Feb March April May June July  

I want the first point to be date always.
Is this possible?

Comment: This is not related to this question. Ask a different one, and make sure you put in enough research before asking.

Comment: Just take a look at this fantastic example by Mike B.: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176.