# Different Colorization on Scatterplot with Shapes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scatter-plot

I just started working on a project using d3.js and SVG. 
I am following the following example as a reference http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3244058#data.csv.
I have modified the code in order to get the data from an external JSON file and I want to have 4 different colors for the arrows depending on specific values' range (could be achieved with simple if conditions I do not have problem with that).
So far I was not able to achieve that. The color seem to change inside the if condition but not as supposed to (for example I give black and it becomes a little bit lighter than before but not black). Any suggestions? So far my code goes like:

```
var color_20c = d3.scale.category20c();
....................... 
... SOME OTHER CODE ...
.......................

var session_data = [];
$.each( punchcard_data, function( playerIndex, player ) {

       $.each( player.SessionData, function( sessionIndex, val ) {
        var rotation;
        var color_fill;

         switch (val.direction) {
              case "UP":
                color_fill="#31a354"    ;   
                rotation="";
                break;
              case "DOWN":
                rotation="rotate(-180)"; 
                break;
              case "LEFT":
                rotation="rotate(-90)"; 
                break;
              case "RIGHT":
                rotation="rotate(90)"; 
                break;
            }
        session_data.push({
                x: val.time,
                y:playerIndex,
                direction:rotation,
                color_fill:color_fill

            });


        });
});
```

and then I have

```
... Some other code ... 
.style("fill", function(d) { return color_20c(d.color_fill); })
```

I can provide the rest of the code if necessary.

Comment: Are you also changing the stroke color? Also if you already have color value then why are you using color scale?

Comment: No the stroke color is the same from the start. Do I have to remove the color scale and explicitly give every time the color I want ? Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle for your query?

Comment: Ok i got it working by removing the color scale.
Now I have a different problem with d3.js tool tip with HTML got any idea on that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576402/dynamic-tooltip-for-multiline-in-d3-js/18576630#18576630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the color scale and directly applying the color will fic your problem. Color scale will map scalar numbers to colors. For example: 1 to red, 2 to yellow, etc. Since you already know the color then you don't need to use the color scale.